# How to pass props from one component to another using optional handling in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks

```
const ViewCategory = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/products", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("List of products", response.data);
        setData(response.data);
        setisLoaded(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isloaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);

  const viewProductVariation = (productId) => {
    history.push("/ProductVariation", {
      productId,
    });
  };

  let products = null;
  if (isloaded) {
    products = data.map((product) => (
      <div className="card">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h4 className="card-title"> {product.name} </h4>
            <p className="card-text"> {product.brand} </p>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => viewProductVariation(product.id)}
            >
              View
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row"> {products} </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  const Id = props.history.location.state?.productId;
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:8080/productVariationDisplay/" + Id, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("List of products variation", response.data);
      setData(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

**I am new to react hooks I am trying to pass productId that is viewProductVariation to another component using react hooks but I am facing an issue I am getting undefined props can anyone tell me how can I pass that productId using optional handling from one component to another using react hooks**

Comment: where do you get the `undefined props`

Comment: Can you show your Route configs

Answer (score 0):

you can use the router hook [`useParams()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) in the destination component to get the paramater values

```js
const { productId } = useParams();
```